# How to add pass thru html in javascript in a notes rich text item

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I am building a XPAGES app. and want to send a url link to the user to specific documents.

In my code I add a rich text style and the link.
The link is not converted to the word "link" with the actual html link on it..
Tried also square brackets around the complete link url.

Any ideas?

```
var nrtStyle:NotesRichTextStyle = session.createRichTextStyle();

nrtStyle.setPassThruHTML(0);

msgbody.appendStyle(nrtStyle);

msgbody.appendText('<a href="' + context.getUrl().toString() + '">link</a>')
```

Comment: Note : This has nothing to do with actual "javascript".  That tag should be removed from the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the SSJS code to send an email to current user with a link to current XPage:

```js
session.setConvertMIME(false);
var doc:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();
doc.replaceItemValue("Form", "Memo");
var body:NotesMIMEEntity = doc.createMIMEEntity();
var header:NotesMIMEHeader = body.createHeader("Content-Type");
header.setHeaderVal("multipart/mixed");
header = body.createHeader("Subject");
header.setHeaderVal("Link to XPage you visited");
header = body.createHeader("To");
header.setHeaderVal(context.getUser().getDistinguishedName());
var stream:NotesStream = session.createStream();
stream.writeText('<a href="' + context.getUrl().toString() + '">Link to XPage</a>');
body.setContentFromText(stream,"text/html;charset=UTF-8", NotesMIMEEntity.ENC_NONE);
stream.close();
doc.send(false);
session.setConvertMIME(true);
```

It creates a new document with an included MIME entity with header and content.
The email sent contains the HTML link in body:

[image]

Look [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.api.doc/r_domino_MIMEEntity_setContentFromText.html) for more information.

Comment: Hi Knut, Tx, I will try this. I was trying via rich text item and passthru because in the app. I am creating I append a rich text item from an existing document to this emails and want to append the link at the end to the email.

Comment: Add the content of current document's rich text item (e.g. 'Body') to this email with `var docBody = currentDocument.getValue('Body');
stream.writeText(docBody.getHTML());` right after createStream() code line.

Comment: Can not get it to work.. the getHTML is trowing an error. For what I see getHTML() works on an XSPDocument and not on a document.

Comment: I tested the code above on Domino 9.0.1 and it worked well.

Answer (score 1):

Why try and do this inside a Rich Text?  Use an XPages Link control directly on your page.

Comment: Hi David, I wanted to do this with a rich text item because first I append a rich text item from an existing document to the email and append the link at the bottom of the emails.   It is part of a workflow script doing a lot of stuf and validations before the actual email is sent.

Comment: ok.  I didn't see in the original question that you were trying to create an email.  I thought this was for an actual XPage